# Substituting values on the command line

Tags: command-line, scripts

I want to run sql from the command line:

```
mysql -u user -p database -e "INSERT INTO table VALUES ( NULL, [hash] , NOW(), 0);
```

I want to replace [hash] with the response of another command line command:

```
date +%s | md5sum
```

Is there a way to make that substitution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, assuming you are using bash (and closing the open quote) -

```
mysql -u user -p database \
  -e "INSERT INTO table VALUES ( NULL, $(date +%s | md5sum) , NOW(), 0);"
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to do it only on the command line, putting it into a shell script was the right thing to do.

Comment: The above will work on the command line too; assuming your shell is bash.

Comment: Thanks, I see, yes that works on the command line as well

Comment: Instead of $() you can wrap the command in backticks and it will work in any shell.  It's also one less character to type ;)